# Updating the center of a force-directed graph in D3

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have a force directed graph in D3. It starts off something like this:

```
let width = this._divElement.offsetWidth, height = this._divElement.offsetHeight;
let svg = d3.create("svg");

let resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {

    width = this._divElement.offsetWidth;
    height = this._divElement.offsetHeight;

    svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
});

resizeObserver.observe(this._divElement);

let g = svg.append("g");

let simulation =
    (d3.forceSimulation() as Simulation<StatusNodeDatum, NodeDependencyDatum>)
        .force("link", d3.forceLink<StatusNodeDatum, NodeDependencyDatum>().id(d => d.id).distance(175))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius((n: StatusNodeDatum) => 32))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

...
```

However, when I resize the graph, I would like to center the graph according to the new width and height of the wrapper element (_divElement).

This happens when e.g. I go to fullscreen or when the window is stretched.

How can I center the graph after the graph has been initialized?

Comment: I think if you just redraw the graph on resize it should be fine.

Comment: How do I do that? :) I guess I must define the new center somehow

Comment: simulation.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2)).restart(); seems to have done the trick. thanks!